Excel Alternatives to INDIRECT
In an overview sheet, I sum up conditionally selected values from other sheets.
In the formulas, I´m using the INDIRECT function to access the different sheets.
In the overview sheet I use hidden cells that I manually populate with references to the other sheets, e.g. $G15 (a cell in the overview sheet) points to '01_sheet'!$Q$4:$Q$661 which contains the values to be summed up.
I've tried a few things using INDEX and CHOOSE but I'm stucking on it.
Now I would like to replace INDIRECT for performance reasons.
The formula I am currently using looks like this:
=SUMPRODUCT(    --((INDIRECT($H15)=Calc_value_one_off) + (INDIRECT($H15)=Calc_value_recurring))*(--((INDIRECT($D15)=$J15)*(INDIRECT($E15)=$K15))*(   --(  (MONTH(INDIRECT($F15))=MONTH(U$4))*(YEAR(INDIRECT($F15))=YEAR(U$4))  ) +  (  --((INDIRECT("'"&$A15&"'"&"!"&U$2&"$"&$B15&":"&U$2&"$"&$C15))="x")*(MONTH(INDIRECT("'"&$A15&"'"&"!"&U$1))=MONTH(U$4))*(YEAR(INDIRECT($F15))=YEAR(U$4))  )>0   ));   INDIRECT($G15)    )


Does anyone have a good suggestion?

what about named ranges? If needed you can combine that with index.

If the sheet or table name is the variable then INDIRECT or VBA is the only way.  If the range is the variable then INDEX can be used.

How many different range references are listed? Will they be subject to change? If not many and not subject to change, what was the try using CHOOSE?

Yes, the main variable is the sheetname.
